# Looping over DIVs using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a set of divs in the following structure:

```
<div id="team">

        <div class="member">
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="member">
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
        </div>      

        <div class="member">
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
        </div>      

        <div class="member">
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
        </div>  

    </div>
```

I want to use jQuery to loop over each div and add a class of floatLeft (if it is an even div) and floatRight (if it is odd). I tried to do it with the following code, but it added floatLeft and floatRight to all divs...

```
var $el,i,$selectedDivs,count;

    $selectedDivs = $('#team > div');
    count = $selectedDivs.length;

    $selectedDivs.each(function() {
        $el = $(this);

        for (i=0; i<=count; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                $el.addClass('floatLeft');
            }
            else {
                $el.addClass('floatRight');
            }
        }
    });
```

I'm guessing it's because of the .each() function...My question is this. Since $selectedDivs is NOT an array, how can I loop over each of those divs using a for loop instead of the .each() function? I purposely want to use it this way rather than jQuery's .odd() and :odd capabilities...

Thanks! Amit

Comment: I'm guessing here but I think you shouldn't be using "#team > div" but "#team div" without the >

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use either a `for` loop or `each`, but not both.

In a `for` loop, you can write `$selectedDivs.eq(i).addClass`.

Comment: Yes, this did it. Thank you very much. I was wondering how to integrate the ith element into the for loop, now I remember the eq(i) part. wonderful.

Answer (score 2):

Your function should be written as follows, instead:

```
var i = 0;
$selectedDivs.each(function() {
    $el = $(this);

    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        $el.addClass('floatLeft');
    }
    else {
        $el.addClass('floatRight');
    }
    i++;
});
```

Comment: This also works. However I did prefer to do it using the for loop method as given by @SLaks. Thanks for your help though, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There's a word I'm looking for, in the Python world it's "Pythonic." A word that means "in line with the common idioms" but for jQuery. "jQueryish?"

```
jQuery("#team > div:even").addClass("floatLeft");
jQuery("#team > div:odd").addClass("floatRight");
```

Comment: I should note also, I always prefer writing out "jQuery" as opposed to using the dollar sign. Why? Some template systems like Cheetah use dollar sign for variable interpolation, you'll be better able to play well with other libraries like prototype, and, heck, repeated strings compress quite well with gzip which most servers use anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is this. Since $selectedDivs is NOT an array, how can I loop over each of those divs using a for loop instead of the .each() function?

Ah but it is. Try this code:

```
int counter = $selectedDivs.length - 1; //zero based so sub one
for (; counter > 0; counter--){ //note I went for the backwards loop here, your preference
   var javascriptElement = $selectedDivs[counter];
   // I like to play with my javascriptElement in the morning
   // I like to play with my javascriptElement in the afternoon
   // I like to play with my javascriptElement in the evening
}
```

And that does *exactly* what you asked.

Comment: It's not technically an array but it does have like one by virtue of Array.prototype.push.apply being called on it.